# How to put two or more listview on the same layout?

Tags: android, listview, layout, android-listview, android-linearlayout

I've tried this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">

     <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1">

          <ListView 
                android:id="@+id/List1" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_weight="1" />

          <ListView 
                android:id="@+id/List2" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_weight="1" />

          <ListView 
                android:id="@+id/List3" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_weight="1" />

          <ListView 
                android:id="@+id/List4" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_weight="1" />
     </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

With no success. This works, but I don't want to divide the `x` screen for all lists, I want to extend the `width` of every list and make it possible to scroll on `x` axis ... 
Does anyone know if I can do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible. In your case it does not work because the `android:layout_width` is set to `fill_parent`, thus the first layout will take all the available space. Try giving `android:layout_weight="1"` to each `ListView`. And remove the inner `LinearLayouts` which are no necessary.

This worked for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_weight="1">

     <ListView 
          android:id="@+id/List1" 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_weight="1" />

     <ListView 
          android:id="@+id/List2" 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I just took your code and remove two of the lists views:

[image]

Comment: Here's an example that does this: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html

Comment: unfortunately does not work ....  i can see only one list ... i want horizontal scroll and vertical scroll .. but now i can vertical scroll on one list ...

Comment: ok ... i'll do ... now i can see four list but i want to extend the width of every list and make possible to horizontal scrool it ... i'll edit the xml file now ... thanks

Comment: @Cristian i've edited the xml file ... and description .. thanks

Comment: I edited my answer... the only different thing I did was removing an unnecessary `LinearLayout`.

Comment: @Cristian, i've the same result but i want that every List width is n't divided in egual part of screen ... i want to make possible to set manually the width of the list and all the list overflow the screen width ...

Comment: Then, set the width manually. Instead of using fill_parent use something like: 100dip, or 125dip or the value you want.

Comment: i'll do this but don't work ... seem that list does'nt support horizontal scrolling ...

Comment: That's right... it does not... it makes no sense to have horizontal scrolling on a list view.

Comment: Cristian i've approved your answer because you correctly aswer to my question and i'don't explain well my question (damn .. my poor english ! )... i resolved the last problem adding this code in my xml ... thank you very much for your support ...  : `<ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
 android:layout_weight="1" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:fillViewport="true">
 <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">`